# How can I programatically Pin an AutoHide window?

Tags: dockpanel, dockpanel-suite

I have an AutoHide ToolWindow that I want to Pin dynamically in the C# application.

Thanks
Chuck

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the `DockContent.DockState` from one of the auto hide ones to its equivalent non auto hide state.

Comment: If only everything was that simple. Thank you.